# What is the proper preposition in this context? steps in/of/for

Tags: word-choice

I have the following sentence which I want to perfect:

> This document describes the basic steps **(of/in/for)** creating a new
>   document.

What is the correct word to use?

Comment: You'd normally say "for", I'll leave it for someone who can explain *why* to answer.

Comment: To expand on the comment though: you could say "the basic steps **of document creation**", "the basic steps **involved in document creation**", or "the basic steps **for creating** a new document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question.

I suggest you to use "*basic steps **of** creation of a new document*" rather than "basic steps **in** **new document creation**".

Therefore, although it is possible, **for** should not be used in your sentence in my opinion.

You can check [Talk English](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx) for further information. I only put what is related to your question hereinbelow:

> **of** is used for belonging to, **relating to**, or connected with:
>
> - *The secret of this game is that you can’t ever win.*
> - *The highlight of the show is at the end.*
> - *The first page of the book describes the author’s profile.*

*and*

> **in** is used with a noun, or a present participle form of a verb, to show what will result from some other action (**[in - WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/in)**):
>
> - *In showing his emotions so clearly, he risked losing his advantage.*

*whereas;*

> **for** is used,
>
> **1.** to indicate the use of something.
>
> - *This place is for exhibitions and shows.*
>
> **2.** to mean *because of*
>
> - *I am so happy for you.*
>
> **3.** to indicate time or duration.
>
> - *He’s been famous for many decades.*

I hope this answers your question well.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive response, but you seem to have changed my wording - would it not be OK to say "steps of creating a new document"?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Max that 'for' would work best here:

> [ODO definition of **For**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for): 4. Having (the thing mentioned) as a purpose or function:
>
> e.g. the necessary tools for making a picture frame

An alternative way of writing the sentence would be 'This document describes the basic steps required to create a new document'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Max as well that "for would work best, for the same reasons mentioned above.

Also, though I realize this technique does not always work, searching Google for "steps for creating" shows many usages in context that make it clear this is the usage you want.

https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=%22steps%20for%20creating%22

For example: "Discover five steps for creating an adaptive performance management process"